# Gradle build error in Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-3.0

Can you please help me to resolve the Gradle build issue in Android 3.0 ?

I am new with Android Studio.
Here are my configurations in the AS 3.0:

gradle->wrapper->gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.2.1-all.zip
```

build.gradle dependencies (Android Plugin for Gradle):

```
dependencies {classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'}
```

[image: Android Studio->Settings]

[image: Android Studio Project Structure]

Stacktrace from Android Studio:

```
D:\AppiumAutomation\MobileTest>gradlew assemble --stacktrace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'MobileTest'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification pat
h to requested target
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification pat
h to requested target
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? If not, should you be?

Comment: Hi cricket_007: No I am not behind a proxy.

Comment: Well, the error is network related. It can't get  an SSL certificate for those `https` sites

Comment: The work station where I am trying is under a corporate network and am working remotely over VPN ('mstsc' - remote desk top connected). Does this make any difference ?

Answer (score 7):

It's a problem related to Android Studio 3.0 and the corporate networks. I had the same problem.

```
Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.
    > Could not resolve com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1.
      Required by:
          project :app
       > Could not resolve com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1.
          > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/test/runner/1.0.1/runner-1.0.1.pom'.
             > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/test/runner/1.0.1/runner-1.0.1.pom'.
                > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    > Could not resolve com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1.
      Required by:
          project :app
       > Could not resolve com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1.
          > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/test/espresso/espresso-core/3.0.1/espresso-core-3.0.1.pom'.
             > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/test/espresso/espresso-core/3.0.1/espresso-core-3.0.1.pom'.
                > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I leave you 2 solutions:

1rst:
You must add certificates manually to your java security certs (used by Android):

C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\security\cacerts

### SOLUTION 01 (Didn't work for me):

Go to:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin
```

Download the Certificate you need (just copy the URL with the problem and paste it into `<remote_host_name>`):

```
keytool -J-Dhttps.proxyHost=<proxy_hostname> -J-Dhttps.proxyPort=<proxy_port> -printcert -rfc -sslserver <remote_host_name:remote_ssl_port> > <name.cer>

Example:
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin>keytool -J-Dhttps.proxyHost= proxy.mycompany.com -J-Dhttps.proxyPort=80 -printcert -rfc -sslserver https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/test/runner/1.0.1/runner-1.0.1.pom > maven2.cer
```

And run the command:

```
keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -keystore ..\lib\security\cacerts -importcert -alias <AliasName> -file <name.cer> -storepass <cacertsPassword>
```

If you never changed the password of cacerts the default one is `changeit`:

```
Example:
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin>keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -keystore ..\lib\security\cacerts -importcert -alias Maven -file maven2.cer -storepass changeit
```

### SOLUTION 02 (Worked for me):

Download the pom entering to the URL site and store it in your local repo:

```
Ex:
If your missing resoruce is:
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/test/espresso/espresso-core/3.0.1/espresso-core-3.0.1.pom

Download it and put it in:
C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/test/espresso/espresso-core/3.0.1/espresso-core-3.0.1.pom
```

Comment: try solution 2 but after that get new error Error:Failed to resolve: play-services-places
<a href="openFile:/Application/build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: Can confirm that as of December 2019 this is still an issue, however, Option 1 does work.

Answer (score 1):

I phase the same issue i formate the android studio and install 3.0 but issue not resolved
so for resolving  the issue i done following things
1.go to view and seed which files are changed.
2.the files may change after updating the plugins and platform.te
3.so you need to revert all files changes which happen due to plugin updates.
[image]

4.Now you have to notice which files changed and go to each file local history and revert the changes for that suppose gradle file is changes so you need to right click that file and go to local history and than select show history

[image]

you will see two files one which will be for recent changes and one which will show you all the recenct changed files 
so you need to properly select the file which you have changed according time ,date

[image]

in above figure you can see on the left top corner their is a revert option if you click on that all chages will be reverted 
so click on that  revert option and save the changes

[image]

do this with all files which is changed due to gradle plugin update
and sync the project you will solve the issue .

Answer (score -3):

Just add google() in your project level gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Rahul, its already there. Issue is not the one you mentioned [inclusion of google() and jcenter() ]. Root cause is still UNKNOWN !