# Gradle sync failed in Android Studio 4,0,1 on Windows 10

Tags: android, kotlin, certificate, build.gradle

I have created a new empty project in Android Studio API 26 but
Grade sync fails and I get an error "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

as an example of the files gradle need is [that][1] which is return 404

[1]: http://(https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.4.10/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.4.10.pom

Comment: you have to be focused in what you have tried and what you face and avoid sentences like "Can some body help?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle Sync Failed Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.pom'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52604185/gradle-sync-failed-could-not-get-https-dl-google-com-dl-android-maven2-com-an)