# Gradle/react-native: How do I manually install a .pom file (e.g. gradle-3.5.3.pom)?

Tags: java, android, react-native, maven, gradle

I have been struggling with a lot of issues/incompatibilities and errors due to my organization's proxy/internet settings and trying to get a react-native application going.

When I'm trying to get React Native to work (`npx react-native run-android --no-jetifier --port=8088`, the equivalent of `cd android && gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8088` inside the project folder), I get one of the following errors:

1. If java.exe **does not** have an internet connection (as in [android studio gradle error - could not get gradle-2.2.3.pom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60142422/android-studio-gradle-error-could-not-get-gradle-2-2-3-pom) or [Gradle Sync Failed Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.pom'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52604185/gradle-sync-failed-could-not-get-https-dl-google-com-dl-android-maven2-com-an)):

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'HelloWorld'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.3/gradle-3.5.3.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.3/gradle-3.5.3.pom'.
               > Permission denied: connect
```

2. If java.exe **does** have an internet connection:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not connect to the Gradle daemon.
Daemon uid: *random-letters-and-numbers* with diagnostics:
Daemon pid: *some-pid*
```

As you may be able to tell, I am stuck. The only thing I can think of is manually installing the dependencies, instead of them being resolved from some server.