# How to resolve "Gradle Project Sync Failed" on Android Strudio Preview?

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

[> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.

> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha08.
> Required by:
> project :
> > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha08 available for offline mode.
> > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha08 available for offline mode.
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.30.
> Required by:
> project :
> > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.30 available for offline mode.
> > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.30 available for offline mode.

Possible solution:

- Disable offline mode and rerun the build
  ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzu4C.png)

Comment: I toggled gradle offline mode to fix this but it didn't work. Also cleared gradle caches yet the it failed to sync

Comment: I did that too but the issue hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: https://ibb.co/nmyHxFV

Comment: @Android_id i got a "Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.0.0-alpha08/gradle-7.0.0-alpha08.pom'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project" on the console. I also toggle graddle and sync project yet it failed.

Comment: I'm only getting this error whenever i want to use android studio Arctic fox canary8 but the other android studio works fine.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52611119/11298876 might help u

Comment: Thanks a lot... it helped. there was a missing gradle.properties file on android studio.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37380417/android-studio-where-is-gradle-properties-file.. SOLVED!!!.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle Sync Failed Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.pom'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52604185/gradle-sync-failed-could-not-get-https-dl-google-com-dl-android-maven2-com-an)

Answer (score 1):

### `Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 8` doesn't work internally.

I suggest migrating to `Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1) Canary 7` with the following definitions:

#### build.gradle (project)

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha07"
    }
}
```

#### gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.1-bin.zip
```

*Note*: Do not use `distributionUrl=.../gradle-6.8.2-bin.zip` or `classpath "...:7.0.0-alpha08"` since they are associated with the Canary 8 compilation.

---

You also have to install Java 11 and configure it in the project

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk
```

JDK Location: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64`

#### build.gradle (:app)

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()
        useIR = true
    }
}
```

Good Luck

[Install Java 11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52950746/5279996)

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error resolved by disabling ***controlled folder access*** in the Windows 10 defender firewall. Navigate to
***settings>update &security>windows security>virus & Threat protection>Ransomware protection>manage ransomware protection>***toggle the *controlled folder access* to be in grey so that the Gradle daemon can be allowed to make changes to the *\usename.graddle\daemon\graddleversion* folder